# How to style individual listView items in android?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, user-interface

Sorry if this is a bit of a noobish question.
I am used to writing windows 8 apps in JS and CSS, and i am still not very good with java.

I am in the process of making my first android app (note taker).
I have a standard ListView defined in my xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/notesListView"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:divider="#b5b5ae"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I have my note taker app working, but currently the UI is s**t.

i am trying to apply styles to each individual listview items, but i cant find a noobs guide to doing that anywhere.

I want it so that each new note that is added to the list, automatically gets a predefined style (like margins).

Can anyone please tell me the best way of applying styles to each individual listview item from the XML (like setting margins, etc).

And also does anyone know how to dynamically change the individual listview items (like i want to be able to make it so if a user selects a certain color from a dialog, that individual listview item changes BG color).

EDIT 1:

Hi,
Here is the code for my listNotes Activity:

```
   package com.fishingfon.notetakerui;


public class ListNotesActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =   (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    notes.remove(info.position);
    populateList();
    //populateLateCustomAdapter();

    return true;
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        return;
    }
    Serializable extra = data.getSerializableExtra("Note");
    if (extra != null){

        Note newNote = (Note)extra;
        if (editingNoteId > -1){

            notes.set(editingNoteId, newNote);
            editingNoteId = -1;
        }
        else {

            notes.add(newNote);
        };
        populateList();
        //populateLateCustomAdapter();

    }

}



private List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
private ListView notesListView;
private int editingNoteId = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_notes);
    ListView notesListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.notesListView);

    notesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int itemNumber, long id) {

            Intent editNoteIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), EditNotesActivity.class);
            editNoteIntent.putExtra("Note", notes.get(itemNumber));
            editingNoteId = itemNumber;
            startActivityForResult(editNoteIntent, 1);


        }
    });

    registerForContextMenu(notesListView);

    notes.add(new Note("1 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("2 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("3 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("4 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("5 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("6 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("7 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));
    notes.add(new Note("8 Note", "blah blah", new Date()));

    populateList();
    //populateLateCustomAdapter();



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_notes, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    //notes.add(new Note("Added note", "blah", new Date()));
    //populateList();

    Intent editNoteIntent = new Intent (this, EditNotesActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(editNoteIntent, 1);


    return true;


}




        // Populate Method
        private void populateList() {
            List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(Note note : notes) {

                values.add(note.getTitle());
            }

            CustomListAdapter CustomAdapter = new CustomListAdapter();

            notesListView.setAdapter(CustomAdapter);
        }
```

And Here is the apadter Class you gave me, but with my Variable names, etc:

```
class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context mContext;
List<String> mList;

public CustomListAdapter (Context context, List<String> values) {
    mList = values;
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mList.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return mList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// This method is called to draw each row of the list
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // here you inflate the layout you want for the row
    final View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list, null);
    return view;


}}
```

My problem is in the populateList method. i have made the line bold above.
I am not sure what code and parameters to put in my populateList method to create the new adapter.

i was just wondering if you know what code i would use for the:
CustomListAdapter CustomAdapter = new CustomListAdapter();

and what parameters to pass in?.

Thanks Heaps

Thanks in advance

Cheers
Corey B

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your adapter you need to bind your item_list resource with your list of notes like this:

```
class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    List<String> mList;

    public CustomListAdapter (Context context, List<String> list) {
        mList = list;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // This method is called to draw each row of the list
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // here you inflate the layout you want for the row
        final View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_list, null);

        // you bind the layout with the content of your list
        // for each element of your list of notes, the adapter will create a row and affect the right title
        final TextView noteTitle= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.note_title);
        noteTitle.setText(mList.getItem(position));


        return view;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the file item_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then to create the adapter, write in the populate method:

```
    // Populate Method
    private void populateList() {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(Note note : notes) {

            values.add(note.getTitle());
        }

        CustomListAdapter CustomAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, values);

        notesListView.setAdapter(CustomAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, That seems perfect thanks. i just have one question tho. What syntax do i use to set this adapter?. on the previous adapter i used, i used this: "ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);". but that doesnt work for the adapter you gave. Do you know what i would use to set the adapter?. Thanks again. Corey
"

Comment: Did you make the binding of your custom layout with the list? I have updated my post.

Comment: In the getView method, you should check whether the convertView parameter is null. If it is then you should inflate a new layout. If it is not, reuse the same one. This is more economic with system resources and makes for a much more optimised listview.

Comment: Yes, you are right. For this example I wanted to stay as simple as possible. But for a complex custom layout, we should definitely try to reuse the same layout as much as possible.

Comment: Hi, yes i had already written my own item_list. i have updated my original post with my problem. Thanks again, Corey

Comment: Thanks heaps for all your help. That's perfect. Thanks again. Corey

Comment: Oh yes, i didnt know about accepting answers, i think i did it. Thanks, Corey

Comment: Can someone please post a screenshot of above implementation. Thanks